# All generated random value is same

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

This is the code that I wrote, I dont know why all the 50 rgbColor generate the same value even when I wrote the random function in randomRGBValue.

```
var html = '';
var valueArr = [];
var rgbColor;

function randomValue() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    valueArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 ));
  }
  return valueArr;
}

function randomRGB() {
  randomValue();
  var color;
  color = 'rgb(';
  color += valueArr[0] + ',';
  color += valueArr[1] + ',';
  color += valueArr[2] + ')';
  return color;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
  rgbColor = randomRGB();
  html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';
}

document.write(html);
```

To ease understanding of my poor written code,

-> randomValue function is for generating random value from 1 to 255(3 sets) and is pushed into valueArr. valueArr is returned.

Example valueArr = (value1, value2, value3)

-> randomRGB function calls randomValue function and plugs in valueArr value into the color array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you never reset your `valueArr` - you keep making it bigger and bigger. But in your `randomRGB()` function, you always access the first three elements of the array.

You can fix this by just adding `var valueArr = []` inside of your `randomValue()` function and you should be fine.

Comment: Solved! Now I know the importance of variable scope!

Comment: Also!, without changing the scope, by adding valueArr.shift(), is also another way :)

Answer (score 3):

hi you can shorten it like this

```js
function randomRGB() {
  return 'rgb(' + [
    Math.random() * 256 | 0,
    Math.random() * 256 | 0,
    Math.random() * 256 | 0
  ].join(',') + ')';
}
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  html += '<div style="background-color:' + randomRGB() + '"></div>';
}
console.log(html);
```

Comment: Math.random() * 256 | 0 <- does the pipe means to round it?

Comment: yep, Javascript has many tricks that you can use to shorten your code

Answer (score 3):

Because `valueArr` is defined globally, it is not reset to `[]` each time `randomValue()` is called and the next three values are just `push`ed to the end of `valueArr` (**not at all modifying the first three values**).

As a result, when `randomRGB()` constructs its color string, **it looks at the first three values** in `valueArr` (which are always the same since the newly generated random values are being appended to the end of the array).

**Two solutions**:

(1) make `valueArr` a local variable defined inside `randomValue()`

```
function randomValue() {
  var valueArr = [];
  ...
}
```

(2) keep `valueArr` where it is, but reset it to `[]` in `randomValue()`

```
var valueArr;
...
function randomValue() {
  valueArr = [];
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Move globally declared variables valueArr, rgbColor into the respective functions Check the working code here 
Demo: https://codepen.io/karthikdivi/pen/ZJJeoa?editors=0010

```
var html = '';
//var valueArr = [];
//var rgbColor;

function randomValue() {
  var valueArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    valueArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 ));
  }
  return valueArr;
}

function randomRGB() {
  var valueArr = randomValue();
  var color;
  color = 'rgb(';
  color += valueArr[0] + ',';
  color += valueArr[1] + ',';
  color += valueArr[2] + ')';
  return color;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
  var rgbColor = randomRGB();
  html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '">foo</div>';
}

document.write(html);
```

Comment: I didnt realize that rgbColor does not need to be in the global scope variable!

Comment: Actually, your code will run just fine with it in the global scope; however, I believe the suggestion was made since the only place you use rgbColor is in the last for loop. Basically, it would make your code cleaner by having fewer global variables cluttering the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hex color can be a bit easier:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) 
    document.write('<div style="background-color:#' + 
        ('00000'+(Math.random()*(1<<24)|0).toString(16)).slice(-6) + '">.</div>');
```